# Year of publication not appearing in the list of references at the end of a compiled LaTeX document using bibliographystyle{naturemag}

Tags: latex, bibtex, overleaf

I'm new to LaTex, so I am using overleaf to create my citations. My bibliographystyle is naturemag.

My references are not including the year of publication in the reference list.

Here is an example of the output I am seeing.

> Cite these [1, 2]
>
> References
>
> [1] Claw, K. et al. A framework for enhancing ethical genomic research with indigenous communities. Nature Communications 9, 2957. URL https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-05188-3.
>
> [2] Tsosie, K., Yracheta, J., Kolopenuk, J. & Smith, R. Indigenous data sovereignties and data sharing in biological anthropology. American Journal of Physical Anthropology 174, 183–186. URL https://doi.org/10.1002/ajpa2484. 1

Below is a sample of my bib.bib bibliography file

```
@article{claw2018a,
  author = {Claw, K.G. and Anderson, M.Z. and Begay, R.L. and Tsosie, K.S. and Fox, K. and Garrison, N.A. and Consortium, S.internship for In peoples in G.},
  title = {A framework for enhancing ethical genomic research with Indigenous communities},
  volume = {9},
  pages = {2957},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-05188-3},
  doi = {10.1038/s41467-018-05188-3},
  language = {en},
  journal = {Nature Communications},
  number = {1},
  date = {2018}
}
@article{tsosie2021b,
  author = {Tsosie, K.S. and Yracheta, J.M. and Kolopenuk, J.A. and Smith, R.W.},
  date = {2021},
  title = {Indigenous data sovereignties and data sharing in biological anthropology},
  volume = {174},
  pages = {183–186},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/ajpa2484},
  doi = {10.1002/ajpa2484},
  language = {en},
  journal = {American Journal of Physical Anthropology},
  number = {2}
}
```

Below are the LaTeX commands I am running.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{paper}
\author{author}
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


Cite these \cite{claw2018a,tsosie2021b} 

\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice minimal working example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bibtex and not biblatex, so you need to use the less flexible `year` field instead of the `date` field:

```
@article{claw2018a,
  author = {Claw, K.G. and Anderson, M.Z. and Begay, R.L. and Tsosie, K.S. and Fox, K. and Garrison, N.A. and Consortium, S.internship for In peoples in G.},
  title = {A framework for enhancing ethical genomic research with Indigenous communities},
  volume = {9},
  pages = {2957},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-05188-3},
  doi = {10.1038/s41467-018-05188-3},
  language = {en},
  journal = {Nature Communications},
  number = {1},
  year = {2018}
}
@article{tsosie2021b,
  author = {Tsosie, K.S. and Yracheta, J.M. and Kolopenuk, J.A. and Smith, R.W.},
  year = {2021},
  title = {Indigenous data sovereignties and data sharing in biological anthropology},
  volume = {174},
  pages = {183–186},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/ajpa2484},
  doi = {10.1002/ajpa2484},
  language = {en},
  journal = {American Journal of Physical Anthropology},
  number = {2}
}
```